# Multiple reducers interactions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I need advice on organizing the interaction of reducers, in my project I can't combine two reducers into one. I wrote a small [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-reducers-interactions-dbspi4?file=/src/features/counter/Counter.js) in which reducers interact through a component. Is it possible to somehow call sliceCounter.caseReducers.decrement() or sliceCounter.caseReducers.increment() from fetchAsyncCounter.fulfilled which is processed in sliceExtra reducer, i.e. without using the component.

I assume that the ["thunk" functions](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks) or [CombineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) will help me solve the problem, but I can't figure out how to write the code correctly yet.

This code

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { fetchAsyncCounter, selectType } from "./sliceExtra";
import { increment, decrement, selectCount } from "./slice";

export default () => {
  const counterValue = useSelector(selectCount);
  const counterType = useSelector(selectType);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (counterType.payload === "plus") {
      dispatch(increment());
    } else if (counterType.payload === "minus") {
      dispatch(decrement());
    }
  }, [counterType, dispatch]);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="counterValuePrint">{counterValue}</div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(fetchAsyncCounter("plus"))}>
        Increase
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(fetchAsyncCounter("minus"))}>
        Decrease
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

should turn into this code

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { fetchAsyncCounter } from "./sliceExtra";
import {  selectCount } from "./slice";

export default () => {
  const counterValue = useSelector(selectCount);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="counterValuePrint">{counterValue}</div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(fetchAsyncCounter("plus"))}>
        Increase
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(fetchAsyncCounter("minus"))}>
        Decrease
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I'm kind of confused by what you're actually trying to accomplish here, tbh. Can you give more details?  This _feels_ to me like a misunderstanding of how Redux works and is supposed to be used, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: markerikson, thank you. I am thinking about where it is better to place the logic of interaction reducers. I want to take out some pieces of code from the components that process values that affect the work of other reducers so that there is less code in the components. And I want to preserve the transparency of the code so that it is clear that, for example, state.extra.operation affects the operation of stat.counter. While I came up with the idea of using store.subscribe

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this option using [store.subscribe](https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener), see the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-reducers-interactions-forked-r3rybj?file=/src/index.js)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import counterReducer from "./features/counter/slice";
import extraReducer from "./features/counter/sliceExtra";
import App from "./App";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    counter: counterReducer,
    extra: extraReducer
  }
});

function select(state) {
  return state.extra.operation;
}

let currentState;
function handleChange() {
  let previousState = currentState;
  currentState = select(store.getState());

  if (previousState !== currentState) {
    if (currentState.payload === "plus") {
      store.dispatch({ type: "counter/increment" });
    } else if (currentState.payload === "minus") {
      store.dispatch({ type: "counter/decrement" });
    }
  }
}

store.subscribe(handleChange);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Yeah, I think you're definitely confused :( In Redux, reducers are totally separate from components, always.  And you should _not_ be calling `store.subscribe()` in your own code - React-Redux does that internally so it knows when to check for updated state and re-render.  Also, the example doesn't even make sense conceptually. You're dispatching an action, to put state in the store describing an operation, to dispatch _another_ action. That's really not how Redux should be used at all :(